# Microsoft url rewrite 2.1 module download issue

Tags: web-platform-installer

I am trying to install microsoft url rewrite module and not able to. I tried to download it via Microsoft wep platform installer. Please, see screenshot below. If failed just like I was trying to download it directly from the browser. In the browser, it will throw invalid SSL certificate error from the download website.[image]

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue and install the url rewrite module? I'm beginner with IIS and it's related technologies. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429383/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-and-sunsetti

Web Platform Installer was being decommissioned when you attempted to install.

You can search and download the MSI packages from [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download).